# Make android phone as USB Webcam

Tags: rooting, usb, 5.1-lollipop, camera, webcam

I have an Android tablet based on Android Lollipop (5.1.1) and I want to use this device as a webcam via USB.

I know some apps could work (e.g. DroidCam or WO WebCam) but they require extra clients installed on a Windows / Linux computer.

Is there any way that I can add an extra option to the USB connection settings that will allow the tablet to be used as a webcam instead of a media device?

Please note I am not asking for apps that can read videos from OTG USB webcams. It's the reverse, making Android output a video feed to a separate computer via USB.

Comment: Does your tablet support HDMI/MHL over USB?  Otherwise this could require kernel hacks. You're trying to do something with a device which was never meant to do it, so...

Comment: No Device does not support HDMI/MHL over USB.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury can suggest me where to change in kernel?

Comment: I can't, and neither can anyone else on this site. This is because kernel hacks relate to development, and development-related questions are considered off-topic on this site. You may have more luck over at the XDA forums for your device.

Answer (score 0):

Driodcam works fine for mine Lenovo tablet- skype and all video programs now recognize it as camera, therwise, i havent found anything that works, tried vysor, but that didnt work....